# Disable an Array element and show Sum of other same Array elements in that disabled field using Lime Survey?

Tags: javascript, limesurvey

Does anyone know how to Disable an Array element and show Sum of other same Array elements in that disabled field using Lime Survey?

For example: we have Question type: Array (Texts)

Array (xx1,xx2,xx3,xx4)

Here I want to disable xx1 field and show Sum of xx2 and xx3 in the disabled field.

I tried disabled the field with following codes (based on search results) but none of them seems to work

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('array-multi-flexi[id="q1_x1_y1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('array[id="q1_x1_y1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[name="q1_x1_y1"]').hide();
       $('array-multi-flexi[name="q1_x1_y1"]').hide();
       $('input[name="#answertextq1_x1_y1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   });
 </script>
```

Question in the form of an image

[image: x]

Thanks

Comment: Found a solution to my question. If anyone has similar case below is my code:

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my question. If anyone has similar case below is my code:

desc:

1. #limesurvey is the main form name.
2. parseFloat function is used otherwise values are appended as if strings.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[id="answer752589X30X2319x1_y1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');});
    
    $("#limesurvey").on("change", function(event) { 
         var k = parseFloat($('input[id="answer752589X30X2319x2_y1"]').val());
         var l = parseFloat($('input[id="answer752589X30X2319x3_y1"]').val());
         var m = k+l;
         $('input[id="answer752589X30X2319x1_y1"]').val(m);
});
</script>
```